# Include filename and line number in stacktrace from ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, csproj

In .NET full framework, it is possible to include the filename and line number in a stacktrace generated from a release build, by including debug info in the output and setting Debug info to `pdb-only` or `full`. When working in ASP.NET Core and Azure Function Apps, these options no longer seem to be accessible through the UI or working if adding the generated XML to the project file. When I create a new project and run it in Release mode, filename and line numbers aren't part of the stacktrace.

How would I include filename and line number on a release build in ASP.NET Core?

Update: Steps to recreate!

Add a new exception logging middleware:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
});
```

Throw an exception in the default generated `ValuesController`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Build the project (debug/release doesn't matter). Run the application using the exe file and hit /api/values. Stacktrace doesn't contain filename and line numbers:

```cs
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at WebApplication50.Controllers.ValuesController.Get()
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

*(I don't want this to turn into a pros/cons post. I know that some people think that including these information is a death sin and some don't :)*

Comment: I have created .Net Core console application and added method that throws exception. Then I've built the application with `dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64` command. When application is launched, exception with source filenames and line numbers is dumped to the console (Here is a [screenshot](https://snag.gy/KAn6tx.jpg)). Do you have any clues what make the difference with your project?

Comment: @CodeFuller I see your point. Just created a new .NET Core console app and both Debug and Release builds output stacktrace with filename and line number. The problems appear to be in Web Apps, Function Apps and similar project types. I'll re-formulate the questions. Thanks!

Comment: Still can't reproduce your case. Default ASP.NET Core Web Application dumps filenames & line numbers in stacktrace - https://snag.gy/FJ8opm.jpg

Comment: @CodeFuller Questions is updated with steps to reproduce.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce your problem with the updated steps from the question. Could you please put the test project for which filenames aren't dumped to github?

Comment: @CodeFuller I think you're right. Cannot seem to reproduce either. Must be something in my current app that causes the missing info. Thanks!

Comment: Try clean rebuild and see if it helps. Also if you could disable parts of the app and try and isolate if there some component or some code that causes the issue to occur just in your project

Answer (score 2):

To have stack traces with line numbers:

- Go to project properties
- Build
- Advanced
- Debugging Information = Full (be sure to do that in Release Configuration)

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp?view=vs-2017#output

(For some weird reasons, I still have some stack traces without line numbers, but that another issue)